# Is the existence and uniqueness of the state-value function for $\gamma < 1$ theoretical?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, value-functions, sutton-barto, policy-evaluation

Consider the following statement from [4.1 Policy Evaluation](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node41.html) of the first edition of Sutton and Barto's book.

> The existence and uniqueness of $V^{\pi}$ are guaranteed as long as
> either $\gamma  < 1$ or eventual termination is guaranteed from all
> states under the policy $\pi$.

I have a doubt on the first condition $\gamma < 1$. If $\gamma < 1$, then it makes our task easy in a way that the $\gamma^k$ becomes zero for sufficiently higher $k$ and it is totally based on the hardware architecture. But, in theory, $\gamma^k$ can never be zero. It may approach zero.

In this context, how can the condition $\gamma < 1$ assure the existence and uniqueness of $V^{\pi}$ theoretically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, your question is about convergence of [infinite series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)). The mathematical discipline that studies such series is hundreds (if not thousands) years old an has nothing to do with "hardware architecture".

A basic example of an infinite series is the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

$$ S = 1 + \gamma +  \gamma^2 + \gamma^3 + \dots$$

Note that the series is infinite - no one says that $\gamma^k$ "becomes zero at sufficiently large $k$". To compute the infinite sum we represent it as a limit of partial sums:
$$ S = \lim_{k\to\infty} ( 1 + \gamma +  \gamma^2 + \gamma^3 + \dots + \gamma^k)$$
The partial sum is called the [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) and has a well-known expression for it:
$$ 1 + \gamma +  \gamma^2 + \gamma^3 + \dots + \gamma^k = \frac{1-\gamma^{k-1}}{1-\gamma}$$
As a result, the sum of our geometric series is:
$$ S = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1-\gamma^{k-1}}{1-\gamma} = \frac{1}{1-\gamma}\quad\text{if}\;|\gamma| < 1$$

In Reinforcement Learning we are dealing with similar infinite series. In partcular, when we are talking about returns:
$$R_t = r_{t+1} + \gamma r_{t+2} + \gamma^2 r_{t+3} + \dots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\gamma^kr_{t+k+1}$$
The convergence of this is acutally [discussed in the  Sutton and Barto's book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node30.html):

> If $\gamma < 1$, the infinite sum has a finite value as long as the reward sequence $\{r_k\}$ is bounded.

I guess, the simplest way to prove that would be to use the [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test). Having $\{r_k\}$ bounded means that there exist such number $C$ so that $|r_k| \leq C$ for all $k$. So we've got the dominating series for the return :
$$ \left|\gamma^kr_{t+k+1}\right| \leq C |\gamma^k|$$
And, since the $\gamma^k$ series absolutely converges for $0 \leq \gamma < 1$, so does $\gamma^kr_{t+k+1}$ series.